# Websocket Connection error occurring every 10 minutes

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

I am **using Websocket with PHP** in a script. It has been running fine for many days now. But today I have been running into some issues.

I have been getting the following **error**:

> {}Empty read; connection dead?  Stream state:
>   {"stream_type":"tcp_socket/ssl",
>   "mode":"r+","unread_bytes":0,"seekable":false,"timed_out":false,"blocked":true,"eof":true}

This keeps happening after 10 minutes of opening the websocket.

Comment: Maybe the connection was terminated by the proxy layer (`nginx` / `apache` / whatever) due to a connection timeout?

Comment: That's what I figured that it could be a timeout error. But this script has been running for many days now and we restart it everyday. This hasn't happened ever before.

Comment: Hey, did you fix that?